# Fine tuning stat_ellipse() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a  scatter plot of bivariate normal distribution with 95% "exact" confidence ellipse.

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e3
c95 <- qchisq(.95, df=2) 
rho <- 0.8  #correlation 
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), 2, 2) # Covariance matrix
```

I generated 1000 observations from bivariate normal with mean zero and variance =`Sigma`

```
x <- rmvnorm(n, mean=c(0, 0), Sigma)
z  <- p95 <- rep(NA, n)
for(i in 1:n){
  z[i] <- x[i, ] %*% solve(Sigma, x[i, ])
  p95[i] <- (z[i] < c95)
}
```

We can draw the 95% confidence ellipse on the top of scatterplot of the generated data with ease using `stat_ellipse`. Resulting figure is completely satisfactory until you note that the several of the red points lie inside the confidence ellipse. I guess that this discrepancy comes from the estimation of some parameters, and disappears as the sample size gets larger.

```
data <- data.frame(x, z, p95)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_point(aes(colour = p95))
p + stat_ellipse(type = "norm")
```

[image: Fig.1]

Is there any way to fine tune `stat_ellipse()` so that it depicts the "exact" confidence ellipse as shown in the figure below which was created using "hand-made" `ellips` function? 
[image]

```
ellips <- function(center = c(0,0), c=c95, rho=-0.8, npoints = 100){
  t <- seq(0, 2*pi, len=npoints)
  Sigma <- matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), 2, 2)
  a <- sqrt(c*eigen(Sigma)$values[2])
  b <- sqrt(c*eigen(Sigma)$values[1])
  x <- center[1] + a*cos(t)
  y <- center[2] + b*sin(t)
  X <- cbind(x, y)
  R <- eigen(Sigma)$vectors
  data.frame(X%*%R)
}
dat <- ellips(center=c(0, 0), c=c95, rho, npoints=100)
p + geom_path(data=dat, aes(x=X1, y=X2), colour='blue')
```

Comment: You wouldn't really expect a random sample to have the same parameters as were used to generate it, would you?

Comment: No, no, I just needed the exact confidence bound for assessment of accuracy of the Gibbs sampling for bivariate normal generation.

Comment: I think you added the center to the `x` and `y` values too early. They end up getting multiplied along with the eigenvectors when they are nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a real answer, but it might help.

By exploring `stat_ellipse` with the following commands,

```
stat_ellipse
ls(ggplot2:::StatEllipse)
ggplot2:::StatEllipse$calculate
ggplot2:::calculate_ellipse
?cov.wt
```

it seems that `cov.wt` is estimating the covariance matrix from the simulated data:

```
cov.wt(data[, c(1, 2)])$cov
#           X1        X2
# X1 1.1120267 0.8593946
# X2 0.8593946 1.0372208

# True covariance matrix:
Sigma
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  1.0  0.8
# [2,]  0.8  1.0
```

You may consider calculating your `p95` values using the estimated covariance matrix. Or just stick with your own well-executed ellipse drawing code.

Answer (score 4):

The ellipse code proposed in the original question is wrong. It works when the X1 and X2 variables have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1, but not in the general case.

Here is an alternative implementation, adapted from the [stat_ellipse](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ellipse.R) source code. It takes as argument the vector of means, the covariance matrix, the radius (computed with the confidence level for instance) and the number of segments for the shape.

```r
calculate_ellipse <- function(center, shape, radius, segments){
# Adapted from https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ellipse.R
    chol_decomp <- chol(shape)
    angles <- (0:segments) * 2 * pi/segments
    unit.circle <- cbind(cos(angles), sin(angles))
    ellipse <- t(center + radius * t(unit.circle %*% chol_decomp))
    colnames(ellipse) <- c("X1","X2")
    as.data.frame(ellipse)
}
```

Let's compare both implementations:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)  # mvrnorm function, to sample multivariate normal variables
set.seed(42)
mu = c(10, 20)  # vector of means
rho = -0.7      # correlation coefficient
correlation = matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), 2)  # correlation matrix
std = c(1, 10)  # vector of standard deviations
sigma =  diag(std) %*% correlation %*% diag(std)  # covariance matrix
N = 1000  # number of points
confidence = 0.95  # confidence level for the ellipse

df = data.frame(mvrnorm(n=N, mu=mu, Sigma=sigma))

radius = sqrt(2 * stats::qf(confidence, 2, Inf))  # radius of the ellipse

ellips <- function(center = c(0,0), c=c95, rho=-0.8, npoints = 100){
# Original proposal
    t <- seq(0, 2*pi, len=npoints)
    Sigma <- matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), 2, 2)
    a <- sqrt(c*eigen(Sigma)$values[2])
    b <- sqrt(c*eigen(Sigma)$values[1])
    x <- center[1] + a*cos(t)
    y <- center[2] + b*sin(t)
    X <- cbind(x, y)
    R <- eigen(Sigma)$vectors
    data.frame(X%*%R)
}

calculate_ellipse <- function(center, shape, radius, segments){
# Adapted from https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ellipse.R
    chol_decomp <- chol(shape)
    angles <- (0:segments) * 2 * pi/segments
    unit.circle <- cbind(cos(angles), sin(angles))
    ellipse <- t(center + radius * t(unit.circle %*% chol_decomp))
    colnames(ellipse) <- c("X1","X2")
    as.data.frame(ellipse)
}

ggplot(df) +
    aes(x=X1, y=X2) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point() +
    geom_path(aes(color="new implementation"), data=calculate_ellipse(mu, sigma, radius, 100)) +
    geom_path(aes(color="original implementation"), data=ellips(mu, confidence, rho, 100))
```

[image]